# Code is compliling and running but highlight errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, artoolkit

I am building AR app using [ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org/) but when I import any example it **highlight errors** in `.cpp` files.

[image: android studio screenshot]

From the errors in the file:

- On first `JNIFUNCTION_DEMO`: `Error after macro substitution: Can't resolve type 'Java_org_artoolkit_ar_samples_ARSimpleNativeCars_SimpleNativeRenderer_demoInitialise'`
- A lot of `unexpected symbol`

Although the examples are **compiling correctly** and working, but because of this problem all of the editing features are not working like auto-complete.

I thought Android Studio doesn't support *c++* and *jni* yet, so I tried *hello_jni* example and it's working perfectly without highlighting errors.

I spent all day trying to fix the problem but I couldn't find any solution.

My OS is Fedora 24.

Comment: Hi, currently ARToolKit it build using the ndk-build, Application.mk and Android.mk toolchain. We work on switching this to the gradle build chain to get everything build from within Android Studio. However for now that is not jet implemented. We would highly appreciate any contribution to get ARToolKit native part build from within Android Studio. Feel free to reach out to me to discuss the current state and what we are up to.

Comment: @Gizmo how can I reach you to discuss that ?

Comment: thor_artk@outlook.com